# CRUD with cake php and jqgrid

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jqgrid, crud

I am trying to use the jqgrid with cake php, the pagination works, but Add,Create,Delete records do not work.

**Method edit**

```
public function edit(){

    $this->autoRender=false;
    $oper='';

    $oper=$this->request->query['oper'];        
    if($oper=='add'){
     echo 'Add record';
    }

    if($oper=='edit'){
     echo 'edit record';
    }

    if($oper=='del'){
     echo 'delete record';
    }
  }
```

`$oper=$this->request->query['oper'];` shows Undefined index: oper [APP\Controller\PeopleController.php, line 16]

If I use `$_POST['oper']` works.

Pagination works and I am using the same to receive variables.

```
     $page = $this->request->query['page'];
     $limit = $this->request->query['rows'];
     $sidx = $this->request->query['sidx'];
     $sord = $this->request->query['sord'];
```

**Jqgrid**

```
$('#tb_people').jqGrid({
            url: "<?php echo $this->request->base ?>/people/listxml",
            datatype: 'xml',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Doc', 'Name', 'Telephone','Adress','Sex'],
            colModel: [
                {
                    name: 'id', 
                    index: 'id',
                    width: 80
                },

                {
                    name: 'doc', 
                    index: 'doc',
                    width: 200,
                    editable:true
                },

                {
                    name: 'name', 
                    index: 'name', 
                    width: 200,
                    editable:true
                },

                {
                    name: 'telephone', 
                    index: 'telephone', 
                    width: 80,
                    editable:true
                },
                {
                    name: 'adress', 
                    index: 'adress', 
                    width: 80
                },
                {
                    name: 'sex', 
                    index: 'sex', 
                    width: 80,
                    editable:true
                }],
            rowNum: 5,
            rowList: [5,10,20,30,50],
            pager: '#dv_paginador',
            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            xmlReader: {
                root: 'rows',
                row: 'row',
                repeatitems: true,
                id: '[id]'
            },
            caption: 'People',
            height: '100%',
            editurl:"<?php echo $this->request->base ?>/people/edit"
        }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#dv_paginator', {
            search: false
        });;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the following.

With $_POST is necessary to use `$this->request->data('something')`

With $_GET is necessary to use `$this->request->query['something']`

The complete source code is [here](http://www.lax-soft.tk/index.php/programacion/php-y-jquery/4-crud-con-jqgrid-y-cakephp)